# I'm trying to use Dialog headless ui as a way to open a modal out of my dropdown, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked

Tags: vue.js, dialog, modal-dialog, vuejs3, simplemodal

Apologies as I'm new to headless ui and vue in general. I have a dropdown in my parent component that works. What I'm trying to do is use dialog to open a modal upon clicking the button in the dropdown. The issue is everyway I have thought to try either causes the dropdown to flash open and close, or the dropdown to open, allow me to click the modal button, but nothing happens, no modal appears. Below is my code for the dialog modal:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
    <button type="button" @click="openModal" class="rounded-md bg-black bg-opacity-20 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-opacity-30 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75">
      Open dialog
    </button>
  </div>

  <TransitionRoot appear :show="isOpen" as="template">
    <Dialog as="div" @close="closeModal" class="relative">
      <TransitionChild as="template" enter="duration-300 ease-out" enter-from="opacity-0" enter-to="opacity-100" leave="duration-200 ease-in" leave-from="opacity-100" leave to="opacity-0">
        <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
      </TransitionChild>

      <div class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
        <div
          class="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center"
        >
          <TransitionChild as="template" enter="duration-300 ease-out" enter-from="opacity-0 scale-95" enter-to="opacity-100 scale-100" leave="duration-200 ease-in" leave-from="opacity-100 scale-100" leave-to="opacity-0 scale-95">
            <DialogPanel
              class="w-full max-w-md transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all"
            >
              <DialogTitle
                as="h3"
                class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Payment successful
              </DialogTitle>
              <div class="mt-2">
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                  Your payment has been successfully submitted. We’ve sent you
                  an email with all of the details of your order.
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="mt-4">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-blue-100 px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500 focus-visible:ring-offset-2"
                  @click="closeModal"
                >
                  Got it, thanks!
                </button>
              </div>
            </DialogPanel>
          </TransitionChild>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Dialog>
  </TransitionRoot>

</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import {
  TransitionRoot,
  TransitionChild,
  Dialog,
  DialogPanel,
  DialogTitle,
} from '@headlessui/vue'

const isOpen = ref(true)

function closeModal() {
  isOpen.value = false
}
function openModal() {
  isOpen.value = true
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of posting the question every day, please update your original question which I had left a comment on and was willing to help solve but you never responded.  I looked into reproducing your issue and your code works perfectly, meaning you've likely not configured something correctly.  My guess is since you're not seeing anything happen that you've not installed [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) which headlessui is an extension of.

Comment: @yoduh The post you commented on was a different way of trying to create the modal on the dropdown. Since that post, I was asked to use Dialog, DialogPanel, etc. from headlessui. Also, the code didn't work perfectly. The code allows for a popup that closes whenever a user clicks anywhere which is an issue on both the web app layout and mobile layout. Also, I have installed tailwind css, as I'm using elsewhere in my code on other pages.

Comment: Sorry, is the issue that you need help with how the modal should close?  The question makes it seem like there's an issue with simply opening the modal.  The code provided so far has no issues that I can see: [stackblitz repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-headlessui-a1fyhm?file=src/App.vue).  Can you provide more code to fully reproduce the issue?

Comment: For the issue you just mentioned, the 'close on outside click' functionality is [built directly into the component](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/main/packages/%40headlessui-vue/src/components/dialog/dialog.ts#L188) with no ability to disable it (outside of forking the project and deleting the functionality yourself).  If that's a hard requirement for your modal you'll need to build your own modal component or find an alternative third party component/library to use.

Comment: The issue ended up being that the code was inside a div causing the modal to render inside the popover. To fix it I had to move the code outside of the popover entirely. Now it's working as expected.